# edited keyboard symbols in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc . Firefox ignores it

Tags: x11, keyboard, firefox

I wanted to play/pause audio on keyboard, but unfortunately my laptop keyboard doesn't have any of those media/function keys. It only has some I don't need (like disable trackpad), but I found out somewhere that these function keys can never be remapped, that they go directly from the keyboard to the OS.

So I chose <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to emit XF86AudioPlay. And modified `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` accordingly.

It works fine in Ubuntu's Videos, but not in Firefox. (It does not work in Rhythmbox either, but I get no sound from that anyway..)

It totally undermined my understanding of how key presses propagate to programs. I thought that the windowing system (strangely enough, not a keyboarding system) provided the apps with the symbols. And I set the windowing system to treat <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> as XF86AudioStop.

However, Firefox (and possibly some other programs, not all though) somehow deduct I pressed End??

Wasn't the point of such a windowing/keyboarding system to not have to define same symbols in every program? To be a middle man between the keyboard and programs? It doesn't seem to behave in that way!

```
➜  ~ xev -event keyboard
Outer window is 0x5000001, inner window is 0x5000002

KeymapNotify event, serial 24, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967234 0   0   0   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x5000001,
    root 0x193, subw 0x0, time 56238457, (588,657), root:(738,872),
    state 0x10, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
"   XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x5000001,
    root 0x193, subw 0x0, time 56247439, (588,657), root:(738,872),
    state 0x10, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x5000001,
    root 0x193, subw 0x0, time 56248610, (588,657), root:(738,872),
    state 0x90, keycode 115 (keysym 0x1008ff14, XF86AudioPlay), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 172
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x5000001,
    root 0x193, subw 0x0, time 56248724, (588,657), root:(738,872),
    state 0x90, keycode 115 (keysym 0x1008ff14, XF86AudioPlay), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 172
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x5000001,
    root 0x193, subw 0x0, time 56249265, (588,657), root:(738,872),
    state 0x90, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

ClientMessage event, serial 28, synthetic YES, window 0x5000001,
    message_type 0x145 (WM_PROTOCOLS), format 32, message 0x143 (WM_DELETE_WINDOW)
```

Comment: 1.  Please run `xev -event keyboard`, focus its window, press your AltGr+End, and add its complete output to the question. Notice that any X11 app has access to both the raw keycodes and to their translations into keysyms and strings, and may decide to ignore the latter. 2. generally, you shouldn't modify anything under `/usr/share/X11/xkb/`; files under `/usr` are under the control of the distro (the next apt-get update may completely wipe your changes, etc). It's better to load the xkb configuration on the client-side with `xkbcomp` -- but unfortunately "modern" DE may not respect it.

Comment: fwiw, in firefox `XF86AudioStop` filters down fine to `MediaStop` in javascript (tested with a `keydown` event listener), but the youtube html5 player ignores it.

Comment: @mosvy I made I typo, I meant `XF86AudioPlay`. `XF86AudioStop` didn't work in Videos either. I'll try `xkbcomp`, if it's not too complicated. I added the output from `xev`.

Comment: It doesn't work either; `XF86AudioPlay` will translate into `MediaPlay` in firefox and `MediaPlayPause` in chromium, but both the youtube player and and the built-in `<video>` player will ignore either of them. I've also tested with a simple key (ie with no modifiers -- 'state 0x0`). A simple browser extension could fix that. Do multimedia keys work in the browser in any OS?

Comment: @mosvy thanks a lot for the test! Yes, I transferred from macos and I think it worked there. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8090453

`By working or browsing and if Safari have some media to show, buttons stop to react for iTunes and is really annoying try to pause/stop/forward/ songs in iTunes just because Safari kidnapped the media buttons [...]`

Comment: You may try saving the following code into an html file, opening it with safari, and pressing those multimedia keys to see how are they different from firefox on linux from the point of view of a web app like the youtube player: `<script> function eshow(e){ document.body.innerHTML += [e.key, e.code, e.keyCode, e.type].join(', ') + '<br>' }; window.addEventListener('keydown', eshow); window.addEventListener('keyup', eshow); window.addEventListener('keypress', eshow); </script>`.